# Automatic variable may not be used in non-procedural constructs

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I'm getting compile error:

> automatic variable may not be used in non-procedural constructs

doing this:

```
task a (logic[31:0] b, int c)
begin
    force global_variable[c] = ~global_variable[c]
end
endtask
```

where `global_variable` is a 49-bit `logic` type variable declared as:

```
logic global_variable[48:0]
```

What I am trying to accomplish from this is to access the specified bit of `global_variable`, as passed on to variable `c` and flip it.

However, there seems to be a problem accessing a specific bit by passing on an integer variable.

Answer (score 4):

There are a few different problems here.

The first is a `force` statement many not contain any expressions with automatic variables. That is because the *lifetime* of the effect of a `force` statement may go beyond the lifetime the the automatic variables. When you exit the task `a`, the automatic variable `c` disappears and there is no longer a valid expression for the force to use.

This is easy to fix on the RHS of the force by using an intermediate static variable.

```
task a (logic[31:0] b, int c)
  static int temp;
  begin
    temp = c;
    force LHS_signal= ~global_variable[temp];
  end
endtask
```

But the next problem is you cannot use a variable as an index select on the LHS of a force, even if that variable is static. There is no way to know when the index changes value if you want a different bit forced and the previous bit released, or just a new bit to force. There are ways around this either by using more complex force expressions, or by using generate for-loop statements that define multiple force statements, each selecting a fixed bit on the LHS.

But before I show you that, I need to point out the last problem; you cannot force a signal to be the inverse of itself. What you can do is force a signal to be the inverse of what is driving it.

```
wire A, B;
wire global_signal

assign global_signal = A & B;

...
force global_signal = ~(A & B);
```

Comment: I don't think i can re-assign the `global_variable` to be a wire or set its value to another, as it is declared as a top level component using OVM

Comment: You cannot use a class member in a `force` statement. Same problem as with automatic variable. This is your first mention of a class-based testbench environment. You are going to need to take a step back and explain your requirements.